# sdiff via php (without shell)

Tags: php, sdiff

Anyone familiar with an equivalent of `sdiff` (or even diff) but executed via PHP. Note: I cannot use `shell_exec()` to execute a bash script. Right now I am pulling in two pages and want to compare to see what the delta is. appreciated

I am trying to compare line by line with the equivalent of
`sdiff -l -w 140 $variable1 $variable2` (which are both  imported via `cURL0`

Answer (score 0):

Check these implementations using PHP:

http://code.iamkate.com/php/diff-implementation/

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/diff